# Creating scatterplot of the relationship between line and points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing, scatterplot

I'm doing an analysis on QGIS for an econometrics class and I'm attempting to show a motivating scatterplot on the relationship between these points which hold data on the proportion of a variable and the distance to the yellow and green lines. I'm just unsure how I can get a scatterplot or another figure to help do that based on these two objects.

[image]

Comment: to clearify: your points already hold the information about the proportion of your data and the distance? If so: why don't you just transfer the data from their attribute table into the vizualization tool of your choice (R, Excel,...) and make the scatterplot there?

Comment: It doesn't hold the distance information -- I'd like to know that also!

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Join attributes by nearest" to get a field with the distance to the nearest line on each point.

Then plot with the tool [Vector Layer Scatterplot](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/plots.html#qgisvectorlayerscatterplot).
(Press Ctrl-Alt-T and search for scatter. )

Comment: Yes, the tools involved cannot handle multiple line or point layers at once.